# NHibernate and making an abstract entity base class

Tags: nhibernate

I saw in some NHibernate examples that an abstract base entity class is used, which has overridden Equals , GetHashCode , to handle transient entities , proxy object (in lazy loading scenario .. I guess) .

Is it really necessary to implement such an abstract base entity class to derive all my entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overridding Equals is definetely required if you want to do lazy loading.
This is because NHibernate relies on the Equals method to determine equality. The default is reference equality.

When NHibernate implements lazy loading, it uses proxy objects, which are subclasses of the real entity class, with every member overridden to enable lazy loading.

Hence for your application to recognise that a proxy object is the same as the object it is meant to be the real instance - it shouldn't be aware of the proxy object at all.

So you must override the Equals operator to intelligently recognise equality (after checking reference equality ... etc) that objects are equal if their IDs are equal.

Comment: I am experiencing trouble in ISet 's Remove() method after I have overridden Equals , GetHashCode . Please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040043/nhibernate-iesi-iset-fails-to-remove  .

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary at all. It just makes things easier because you can put things like the Id on it. As well common functionality like you previously mentioned like Equals/GetHashCode.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the base class itself is not required,but overriding Equals and GetHashcode is something you'll want to do on all your entities, so the base class makes thAt a lot less repetetive

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, having a base class that exposes an Id property is really useful to be able to create generic repository methods that take advantage of that, or for automatic mapping conventions.

Overriding Equals, however, is another story.

Doing so forces loading of uninitialized proxies when you compare them (for example, by calling Distinct on a sequence). For that reason, it's better done only for class hierarchies of seldom-changing entities that are likely to be cached.

Comment: I have to agree with diego here, I use a base abstract class solely for my Id field.

Comment: I am experiencing trouble in ISet 's Remove() method after I have overridden Equals , GetHashCode . Please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040043/nhibernate-iesi-iset-fails-to-remove